# No method to map entity to table in entity framework core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core in a normal .net project, version 4.7. I know I can do this. The problem is that I can't seem to map an entity to a table because the "ToTable" method doesn't exist. I can't edit the poco or entity classes because they are predefined and generated. So I can't use the attribute. I looked on the internet and everyone seems to use this method to map an entity to a table.

Here is my code:

```
public class FactsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TblIncident> TblIncidents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TblAction> TblActions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TblAddressTypeAlias> TblAddressTypeAliases { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TblCountry> TblCountries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //these methods don't exist in my case
        modelBuilder.Entity<TblIncident>(entity => entity.ToTable("Incident"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<TblIncident>().ToTable("Incident");
    }
}
```

I also tried to use IEntityTypeConfiguration with a EntityTypeBuilder but it still don't have access to the map to table method:

```
public class IncidentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TblIncident>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TblIncident> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Incident");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why these methods have been removed? I have been searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below approach. You have to use `Table` data annotation.

**DBContext:**

```
public virtual DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(b =>
    {
        b.Property(e => e.Property1).HasDefaultValue(true);
        ... //Other properties
    }
```

**Model class:**

```
[Table("Article")]
public class Article
{
```

You can also use to `ToTable` in DBContext, but you have to make sure that you have included `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.

Line `modelBuilder.Entity<TblIncident>().ToTable("Incident");` looks correct according to the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables#fluent-api

Comment: The thing is the poco classes are generated from another source and I can't really edit them.

Comment: are you missing using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in dbcontext class?

Comment: `ToTable` is defined in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly.

Answer (score 10):

I looked into the Entity Framework Core repository on GitHub and searched for the method "Totable" inside the repository. It turns out it is defined as an extension method but it is in separate nuget package and library called Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

After I downloaded the package I got the Totable method that I need. Still it doesn't make sense to add that method in a separate package for sql server when you already have the "Table" attribute that you can add on entities directly in the entity framework core package.

Comment: Nope, you didn't mention anything about downloading the sql server nuget package for entity framework core which includes the Totable method that I needed. The Totable method is not included in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace. At least on my version. Could be multiple versions each with its separate quirks.

Comment: My question was about the Totable method and not about ways in which you can map an entity to a table. It was mentioned in the title and in the description that it is about the method and not the attribute "Table"

Comment: Yes, I gave you an alternative approach which is 100 % solving your problem. If there is any constraint then you should mention it in the question.

Comment: Yes, but in the question I didn't mention that I am looking for alternatives. I asked that the Totable method is not found and where can I find it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think it's important for people to know how to find the Totable method too in case they run into my issue in which they can't change the poco/entity. I think I will vote my own answer so other people can see it and not waste time searching for the solution. It is selfish to ask for a vote to this question because other people that need the solution I discovered will ignore it and waste time.

Comment: I didn't ask for a vote anytime. If I answered your question according to the question description. then you should at least appreciate. Its also important to know that there is a very simple way to solve this issue if you dont have any constraint which is not at all present in the question

Comment: Nah, you are right. You are the only one that bothered to answer. Thank you for your attention. I have given you the rating. Also feel free to use the other info I mentioned in my answer into your answer.

Answer (score -4):

It's very old thread but I got the same issue and I solved it by placing `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` as a first line of `OnModelCreating` method.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: That doesn't magically bring a `ToTable` method in scope.